# how to know the intent is finished or not in android

Tags: android

hai every one . im my project while displaying a page  if there are some buttons for displaying videos then if i click on it then the video should play and when i stop the video then i should get the original page with image button. i wrote the code as .......

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(myPath);    
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);    
 myContext.startActivity(intent);
```

In place of mypath i gave the path where the video is located.

Actually my problem is when the video playing is finished  , i am not getting the original page with buttons but empty page with image button. can any body tel where the exasct problem is..
 thank you in advance

Comment: posting code might help us find your 'exact' problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)